# Call modal window from factory method on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I Have a problem calling modal window from factory method on ng-click action.
I've tried 2 ways to call:

```
$scope.AddItem = function ($scope) {ModalWindowService.openAddItemDialog($scope)};
```

in this way, just nothing happens on click. but if i check with `alert()` it works.

```
$scope.AddItem = function () {alert('here');};
```

And if i do this:

```
$scope.AddItem = ModalWindowService.openAddItemDialog($scope);
```

- modal window opens just on page load, not as ng-click function.

So, how do i solve a problem?

This is the example code:

**Main Controller:**

```
    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'ModalWindowService',  function($scope, ModalWindowService){
        //$scope.AddItem = ModalWindowService.openAddItemDialog($scope);
        $scope.AddItem = function ($scope) {ModalWindowService.openAddItemDialog($scope)};
    }]);
```

**ModalWindowService:**

```
app.factory('ModalWindowService',['$modal',function($modal) {
    function openAddItemDialog($scope) {

        $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
        $scope.valueToPass = "I must be passed";

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: '/view/AddItemDialog.html',
            controller: 'AddItemController',
            resolve: {
                aValue: function () {
                    return $scope.valueToPass;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (paramFromDialog) {
            $scope.paramFromDialog = paramFromDialog;
        });
    }

    return {
        openAddItemDialog: openAddItemDialog
    };
}]);
```

**AddItemController:**

```
app.controller('AddItemController',function($scope, $modalInstance, aValue) {
    $scope.valuePassed = aValue;
    $scope.close = function () {
        $modalInstance.close("Someone Closed Me");
    };
});
```

**HTML from there the modal window should be opened:**

```
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-orange btn-block" ng-click="AddItem()">
                Add
            </button>
```

Comment: Remove the `$scope` argument from `AddItem ()`, i.e.: `$scope.AddItem = function () {ModalWindowService.openAddItemDialog($scope)};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, don't pass `$scope` to `$scope.AddItem` function.

```
$scope.AddItem = function () {
    ModalWindowService.openAddItemDialog($scope)};
}]);
```

Comment: thanks, that's it, works! But why shouldn't i pass it? it's a new function.. is it get all variables from controller automatically?

Comment: Glad I could help. In the controller logic you need to pass the `$scope` to the modal service, which you are already doing here `ModalWindowService.openAddItemDialog($scope)`